# System.Threading.Tasks.Task Method Not Found

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

Developing an application and use two different machines.  As far as I know, they are both at the same release of Windows 10 (1803).  Just recently, I have started having an issue on one machine.  The application uses Individual Account Authentication, and at the login prompt, once a user enters their username and password and clicks Login, it throws the following error:

```
Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<!!0> System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(System.Linq.IQueryable`1<!!0>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1<System.Func`2<!!0,Boolean>>)'.
```

The code that it identifies as the issue is (at last line):

```csharp
// To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
//var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false); // <-- this line
```

I have went as far as to completely delete the Project from the suspect machine and re-clone from Git, but the same issue.  I went thru my references and compared against the machine that it is working on and they all match.

Just for reference, here is the stack trace:

```
[MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<!!0> System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(System.Linq.IQueryable`1<!!0>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1<System.Func`2<!!0,Boolean>>)'.]
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.<GetUserAggregateAsync>d__6c.MoveNext() +0
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start(TStateMachine& stateMachine) +94
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.GetUserAggregateAsync(Expression`1 filter) +146
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.FindByNameAsync(String userName) +537
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2.FindByNameAsync(String userName) +56
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.<PasswordSignInAsync>d__29.MoveNext() +104
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +24
   CaseNotesPlus.Controllers.<Login>d__12.MoveNext() in D:\Projects\CaseNotesPlus\CaseNotesPlus\Controllers\AccountController.cs:88
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__11_0() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_1.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2() +228
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__3() +35
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9874329
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +48
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +159
```

I have verified that I have the same NET Framework Setup on both machines: Version Information:

- Microsoft .NET Framework Version: 4.0.30319
- ASP.NET Version: 4.7.3056.0
- The project targets 4.6.1

Comment: Post the code, I'll see what I can see.

Comment: Not sure it has anything to do with the code.  It runs fine on the other machine.  I just cant figure out where to even start looking for the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that you are using **Entity Framework version 6.2**

I had the same issue because I was using the Linq method `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` with a version of EntityFramework 6.1.3 **(before 6.2.0)**

According to Microsoft documentation on "QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync()" :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.firstordefaultasync?view=entity-framework-6.2.0

This method is only available with the version of ** EntityFramework 6.2 **

> ### Applies to
>
> **Entity Framework**
>
> 6.2.0

Comment: I am using efcore 3 and have this error. Is it again related to the version?

Comment: I would say to ensure the compatibility between your Nuget versions because according to EFCore 3 documentation[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.firstordefaultasync?view=efcore-3.0] the function "FirstOrDefaultAsync" applies to the following: 
Entity Framework Core
3.0, 2.2, 2.1, 2.0, 1.1, 1.0

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `PasswordSignInAsync` method at `CaseNotesPlus\Controllers\AccountController.cs`, probably has an action attribute above the method. Maybe it had some kind of machine name specification check.

Comment: Mike,  thanks for the comment, but nothing there that is even remotely machine specific

Answer (score 0):

Check your references and make sure you are not referencing anything from the "gac". That could explain why it works in one machine and not in the other.

Seems to me like your issue is related to your ef version (identity is requiring a diferent version than the one referenced by tour code).  Check your assemly bindings too.